# Change Oracle Database from Archive log mode to Non-archive log mode

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle databse, it is Oracle 11g Standard Edition, Currently it is working in archive log mode. And I need it to be change to non-archive log mode. Because everyday the logs fill the Hard Disks of the server.

Please let me know the steps to do this..

Thanks in advance

Mahesh

Answer (score 4):

To set the database in `NOARCHIVELOG MODE`, You need to shutdown the db & start it in in mount state. Follow the below steps.

```
1. shutdown immediate;
2. startup mount;
3. alter database noarchivelog;
4. alter database open;
```